# Error deploying webapp on Tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat, gwt, tomcat7

I developed an website using google GWT. In development mode everything works fine, but when I try to deploy the project I stumbled with some problems.

I have several websites in this server (most of them don't use java). And I only want to run the app when mydomain.com is typed. So I've added the following entries to tomcat server.xml:

```
 <Host name="mydomain.com" appBase="/var/zpanel/hostdata/mydomain/public_html/mydomain_com"
             unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

        <!--
        <Context path="" docBase="."/>
        -->

        <!--
        <Alias>mydomain.com</Alias>
        -->

        <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
        -->

        <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
             Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

      </Host>
```

The tomcat server is working fine beacuse if I deploy an app using the manager it works. But I can't get this one to work. In appBase I've user the full path to the app folder (it isn't in Catalina base) and the folder mydomain_com contains all that the war would contain. I also wanted to use an alias (and hide the 8080 port) from the user.

It does nothing if I type mydomain.com:8080. If I use another domain in the same server with the 8080 port it sends me to tomcat welcome page installed on ROOT. So I'm guessing its using the entry but its unable to load the app.

What am I doing wrong?

Also I'm using tomcat 7.0.53 in centOS 6.

Thank you for your time

Comment: just a suggestion....did you compile the GWT code?

Comment: @AngeloImmediata Yes I compiled the code. Also I know it's working because if I deploy the .war using tomcat manager it works.